# choise ic gnss for drone

Tags: gnss

I found a company that produces [GNSS IC](https://ntlab.lt/rfic/) . I can't choose between 1065 https://ntlab.lt/product/nt1065/ 1066 https://ntlab.lt/product/nt1066/ I want to build a navigation system for a drone"

Comment: Why can't you choose?

Comment: Why choose? Try both!

Comment: I hope you realize that 1) you need a lot more than only such a chip to make a working navigation system 2) the manufacturer might not even want to talk to you unless you are planning to order thousands or more of these ICs. Explain why you need to build your own while everyone else just uses a module.

Comment: `I can't choose` is not a question .... `I want to build` is not a question either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful, it seems to be only RF Front Ends and not GNSS Modules. So you can't use them directly because it doesn't contains any baseband circuit.

Comment: Yes, this is only the RF frontend. To make a complete navigation system, another chip is needed for data decoding, correlation and to run the software that is needed to determine the position.